# Showing a span element only when hovering over an image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress recently viewed products widget. I would like the name of the product to show up over the image, when you hover over it.

I have it working elsewhere, the difference is than with this widget, the li do not have a class attached. I know the line I need to fix is:

```
.product_list_widget ul li .attachment-shop_thumbnail:hover span.product_title {
```

I just don't know what it should be changed to, to show the span when the image is hovered!

For the first time I got a fiddle to work!

Any ideas?

```css
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
  width: 22%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.recent_view_prod span.product-title {
  display: none;
}
.product_list_widget ul li .attachment-shop_thumbnail:hover span.product_title {
  display: block!important;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1vw;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: .5em!important;
  padding-right: .5em!important;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(160, 163, 162, 0.8);
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  width: 75%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_widgetised_column wpb_content_element recent_view_prod">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div id="woocommerce_recently_viewed_products-3" class="widget woocommerce widget_recently_viewed_products">
      <h3 class="widget-title element-title">Recently Viewed Products</h3>
      <ul class="product_list_widget">
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/opulent-bloom-card-holder/" title="Opulent Bloom Card Holder">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/TedBaker_CardHolderOpulentBloom_2-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="TedBaker_CardHolderOpulentBloom_2"> <span class="product-title">Opulent Bloom Card Holder</span>
          </a>
          <span class="amount">£19.95</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/store-ms/" title="Store-M's Nesting Food Boxes">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/StoreMs1-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="StoreMs1"> <span class="product-title">Store-M's Nesting Food Boxes</span>
          </a>
          <span class="amount">£11.95</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/happy-jackson-crackers-tin/" title="Happy Jackson Crackers Tin">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/HappyJCrackersTIn-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="HappyJCrackersTIn"> <span class="product-title">Happy Jackson Crackers Tin</span>
          </a>
          <span class="amount">£6.99</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/happy-jackson-snack-box-set/" title="Happy Jackson Snack Box Set">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SnackBoxSetx4_2-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="SnackBoxSetx4_2"> <span class="product-title">Happy Jackson Snack Box Set</span>
          </a>
          <span class="amount">£9.99</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use css only solution, you could use `adjacent selector`:

```
img.attachment-shop_thumbnail.wp-post-image:hover + span {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

This targets element immediately after your `img` element, and you don't need to know the class of your span for that.
Only requirement, you'll need to stick to, is that `span` has to be immediately after `img`in your markup.
Another alternative might be `sibling combinator` selector:

```
img.attachment-shop_thumbnail.wp-post-image:hover ~ span {
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
}
```

which only require your `span` element to be after `img` but not necessary immediately.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cLa6a34/) with that.

Comment: Thanks! When I put it into the style sheet it works when you hover the image until you hover of the title then it disappears

Comment: That is natural behaviour since you're not hovering over `img` anymore, but over the `span`. If you want to hover over `link` holding the `img` to display `span`, refer to this [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cLa6a34/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use following selector:

```
ul.product_list_widget li .attachment-shop_thumbnail:hover span.product-title {
    //styles as above
}
```

Your <ul> tag has class "product_list_widget" so following selector:

```
.product_list_widget ul li .attachment-shop_thumbnail:hover + span.product-title
```

wouldn't work, because that would require <ul> to be inside element that has class "product_list_widget".